# JSON decode into english/chinese

Tags: json

Does anyone know how to translate JSON into English/Chinese?

I have a JSON64 file that I want to decode in order to retrieve the information in there.

Thanks

Comment: try this http://jsfiddle.net/patridge/NQ4uE/

Comment: @KishoreSahas What kind of answer is that lol

Comment: Could you please be more clear on your question ?